# Node Js - Converting array to string and adding slash to it

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am learning nodeJS.

**I tried other stackoverlow questions and answers but didn't found the solutions. I am stuck to this from last 2 days.**

Here is the question begins

**angular js code:**

```
$scope.queAns = [{"answer":"truyt","question":"How do you keep list elements straight in an HTML file?"},{"answer":"asc","question":"A sum of money at simple interest amounts to Rs. 815 in 3 years and to Rs. 854 in 4 years. The sum is:"}];
  $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : "http://localhost:8888/answerList",
    withCredentials: true,
    data: $scope.queAns,
    headers : {'Content-Type' :  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  }, function (error) {
    alert("Something went wrong.");
  });
```

**NodeJs code:**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.post('/answerList',urldecodedParser, function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
})
```

**And I am getting output as**

```
{"{\"answer\":\"truyt\",\"question\":\"How do you keep list elements straight in an HTML file?\"},{\"answer\":\"asc\",\"question\":\"A sum of money at simple interest amounts to Rs. 815 in 3 years and to Rs. 854 in 4 years. The sum is:\"}":""}
```

**And I want output as:**

```
[{"answer":"truyt","question":"How do you keep list elements straight in an HTML file?"},{"answer":"asc","question":"A sum of money at simple interest amounts to Rs. 815 in 3 years and to Rs. 854 in 4 years. The sum is:"}]
```

Any help???

Comment: `{'Content-Type' :  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` should probably be `application/json` and then you wouldn't need the `urlencodedParser`

Comment: Try using `res.json(req.body)` instead of `res.send(req.body)`.

Comment: **What port number you are using??** in node code near cross-origins you used **http://localhost:8080** and in angular code you are calling **http://localhost:8888/answerList**

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe  I am created server and using localhost:8888

Answer (score 0):

Back before AJAX was a thing, websites used `<input>` elements inside `<form>` elements to make requests. Each `<input>` had a `name` and a `value` and they were encoded as:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

If the `<form>` was submitted using a GET request then this encoded parameter data would just be appended to the URL. On the other hand, if it was submitted using a POST request it would be sent as the request body using a `content-type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Returning to the present day, this format is alive and well and can still be used to transmit data to a server. In Express the middleware `bodyParser.urlencoded` will decode request bodies that use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format into a flat JS object. Using my example above you'd end up with something like this:

```
req.body = {
    name1: 'value1',
    name2: 'value2',
    name3: 'value3'
}
```

If a parameter is passed without a value, e.g. `name1` in `name1&name2=value2`, it will be treated as though the value were an empty string, so:

```
req.body = {
    name1: '',
    name2: 'value2'
}
```

Now let's imagine we send the JSON data `{"answer":true}` as our request body but we incorrectly use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the `content-type`. The parser will treat `{"answer":true}` just the same as `name1` in our previous example and parse it into:

```
req.body = {
    '{"answer":true}': ''
}
```

To human eyes there's obviously some JSON going on here but to the cold, unforgiving logic of the parser the text `{"answer":true}` has no special significance, it just treats it as a parameter name.

If we then try to bounce this back in the response using:

```
res.send(req.body);
```

it will be JSON encoded to give the response:

```
{"{\"answer\":true}":""}
```

This is what you're seeing, albeit with a much longer piece of JSON. Currently I can't explain where the square brackets have gone in your example, I'd expect to see `[` and `]` at the extremities but it would seem something is consuming them.

To fix this we first need to fix our `content-type`. Rather than using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it should be `application/json`. Then we need an appropriate parser on the server, which would be `bodyParser.json`, e.g.:

```
app.post('/answerList', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {
```

Usually the `bodyParser` would be included separately so it can be shared by all requests. Only requests with a `content-type` of `application/json` would be affected so it shouldn't cause any adverse effects for requests that aren't using JSON:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/answerList', function(req, res) {
```

I highly recommend reading the docs at https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html