# IONIC 3 application not POSTing JSON properly

Tags: json, node.js, express, ionic3

I'm hoping I can get some help with this one. Below is the code I have written to post an email and pin. It all looks good until it reaches the server. The server processes it as:

```
{ '{"email":"email@gmail.com","pin":"1234"}': '' }
```

I'm not sure where the issue is. I've tried sending the email and pin through POSTman and that works without issues. I've even included the header that POSTman creates (Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to make sure that I'm sending all the info the same way.

Here is my Ionic code:

```
export class LoginPage {
  baseURL: string = 'http://localhost:1000/api'
  data: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
  }

  login(email, pin) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body = JSON.stringify({
      email:  email,
      pin:  pin
    });

    console.log(body); //This looks just like it's supposed to

    this.http.post(this.baseURL + '/authenticate', body, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(this.data);
      }, error => {
        console.log("Oooops!");
      });
  };

}
```

Here is the code for my server just in case I'm messing something up there.

```
// ===========================
// get the packages we need ==
// ===========================
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan     = require('morgan');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt     = require('bcryptjs');
var router     = express.Router();

var jwt        = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config     = require('./config'); // get our config file
var models     = require('./app/models/models');

// =======================
// configuration =========
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 1000;
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('secret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// =======================
// routes ================
// =======================
// basic route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

var apiRoutes = express();

// apply the routes to our application with the prefix /api
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// API ROUTES -------------------

//===============================
// Log a user into their account.
//===============================
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); //here I'm getting: { '{"email":"email@gmail.com","pin":"1234"}': '' }
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Stuff happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: See if the answer I gave here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661599/node-js-converting-array-to-string-and-adding-slash-to-it/46672389#46672389 In short, your `content-type` should be `application/json`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried that though and on the server side I get OPTIONS /api/authenticate 403

Comment: I assume that's a CORS pre-flight OPTIONS request. There's lots of info about CORS on the web but https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html might be somewhere to start reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';


//make url params

 let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.append('email', 'test@tst.com');
    body.append('pin', '123456');
```

Use URLSearchParams for the body instead and check